# What happens after an uncaught exception is thrown Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, exception, mobile

I am trying to understand how Android apps behave when a crash occurs. It seems that sometimes when a crash happens the application simply goes back to the previous activity on the stack. I need my application to close completely however as this seems to put it into an undefined state.

Any help would bee greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whenever an application crashes the application is restarted by the Android OS. In some OEM products like samsung if an app crashes a few times they show dialog that application keeps on crashing.

Comment: Maybe catching the exception would be a better approach :) You could do a generic try-catch block, and call system exit in the catch block if you need to, but that doesn't seem like a good idea. From a user perspective, apps should have a fluid and responsive experience, so you might want to reconsider your approach.